# installing Oracle Database 10g XE Server in Ubuntu 11.04, "E: Unable to locate package oracle-xe"

Tags: installation, oracle

I have read many posts for installing Oracle Database 10g XE Server in Ubuntu, such as [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-linux-oracle-database-xe-server/)

But I get an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-xe
```

when execute the command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-xe
```

At the previous step (`sudo apt-get update`), it also notices that

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Did any one meet and solve this problem? I have searched for this problem but got no proper answer.

Comment: The link is broken. Did you mean http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-linux-oracle-database-xe-server/?

Comment: Yes, that's it, I have just repaired it, thanks. Do you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step by step guide for Installing Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 on Ubuntu 12.10

Step 1. Managing Swap partition. Oracle Database Express Edition 11gR2 may require up to a 2GB (2095100 KB) swap partition, Enter the following command in terminal to verify your swap space:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i swap
```

If you don’t have enough swap space, you can increase available swap space by the following guide to create and enable swap partiton, in this case I’ll create 1 GB swap file and loaded at startup, located in the /home directory

Login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

Create swap file on /home directory with following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576
mkswap /home/swapfile
swapon /home/swapfile
swapon -a
```

Create a backup of the original “fstab” file and add the new swap file:

```
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup_`date +%N`
echo '/home/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

Logout from root and verify the new swap space:

```
exit
swapon -s
```

Step 2. Install additional software thats require Oracle 11g Express Edition

```
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1
```

Step 3. Download Oracle Database Express Edition 11gR2 via Oracle Official website, it require registration before downloading.

Step 4. unzip the downloaded file, then convert the Oracle Database Express Edition 11gR2 package installer to debian package

```
unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0.1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
cd Disk1/
sudo alien --to-deb --scripts oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Step 5. Configure Awk and Chkconfig, The following needs to be set for compatibility:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
sudo mkdir /var/lock/subsys
```

Ubuntu uses different tools to manage services and system startup scripts. The “chkconfig” tool required by the Oracle installer is not available in Ubuntu. The following will create a file to simulate the “chkconfig” tool.

Login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

Copy and paste the following Script directly into the terminal to create a file chkconfig:

```
cat > /sbin/chkconfig <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
# Oracle 11gR2 XE installer chkconfig, Only run once.
echo "Simulating /sbin/chkconfig..."
if [[ ! `tail -n1 /etc/init.d/oracle-xe | grep INIT` ]]; then
cat >> /etc/init.d/oracle-xe <<-EOM
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: OracleXE
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Oracle 11g Express Edition
### END INIT INFO
EOM
fi
update-rc.d oracle-xe defaults 80 01
EOF
```

Logout form root:

```
exit
```

Set the file /sbin/chkconfig executable :

```
sudo chmod 755 /sbin/chkconfig
```

Step 6. Install Oracle Database Express Edition 11gR2 with the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Disk1
sudo dpkg -i oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.deb
```

Run the following configuration script to create (clone) the database. Accept the default answers, including “y” to startup the database automatically, or modify as required.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

To verify success, the procedure should end showing:

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...Done
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
Installation completed successfully.

Step 7. Set a password for the Oracle account:

```
sudo passwd oracle
```

Step 8. Post-Installation, In order to use sqlplus and other tools, the Oracle account requires specific environment variables. The following will set these variables automatically at every Oracle login:

Login as the Oracle user:

```
su - oracle
```

Copy the default account skeleton files and add the Oracle env script to .profile:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bash_logout ./ 
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ./ 
cp /etc/skel/.profile ./ 
echo "" >>./.profile
echo '. /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh' >>./.profile
```

Step 9. Configure remote login. By default, the Oracle Database XE graphical user interface is only available at the local server, but not remotely. The following will enable remote logins:

Login as the Oracle user, then login as SYSDBA and run the following commands:

```
su - oracle
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

That version of Oracle seems to be pretty old (May 2006).

You can download a newer version directly from Oracle. It seems to come in .rpm format, but you can use [alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) to convert that to `.deb`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I have just got "oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0. 1-1.0_i386.deb" from "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/102xelinsoft-102048.html". Then what can I do next with this .deb file. Sorry, I am quite new with linux :)

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully installed Oracle on my Ubuntu computer, just by using oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0. 1-1.0_i386.deb from Oracle site. :)

Comment: It seems you have figured it out yourself, but the command to install a .eb package file is `sudo dpkg -i package-file-name.deb`